# GRG Non linear constraint solver for iOS suggestions

Tags: ios, objective-c, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Can any one suggest equivalent iOS SDK similar to GRG Non-linear solver in Excel ?

Which can be a c/c++ solution and can be easily integrated into iOS i.e to solves non-linear equations similar to EXCEL GRG Non linear Solver.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at RASON which is a JSON based modeling language and REST API. Once you model your problem in RASON format, you can call GRG solver, the exact same solver used in Excel, or choose other non-linear solvers available.

Disclaimer: I used to work at Frontline Systems, the developers of RASON.